# Android: cannot get values using .getStringExtra

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, bundle

I'll just go straight to the problem. In `UploadNotesActivity.java`....

First, I pick a .pdf file using intent

```
chooseNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_FILE);
        }
    });
```

and then, in `onActivityResult, I save the filePath of the picked file.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        data.putExtra("filePath", data.getData().getPath());
        choosenFile.setText(data.getStringExtra("filePath"));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in choosing file",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

click `Upload` button to start upload the file

```
 uploadNotesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onUploadButtonClick();
        }
    });
```

the `onUploadButtonClick()`

```
private void onUploadButtonClick() {
    final String serverUrlString = "http://XXXX/uploadNotes.php";
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath").isEmpty()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "filePath is null");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath"));
    }
    final String fileToUploadPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath");
    final String paramNameString = "uploaded_file";

    String fileName[] = fileToUploadPath.split("/");

    final MultipartUploadRequest request =
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), serverUrlString);

    request.addFileToUpload(fileToUploadPath, paramNameString,
            fileName[fileName.length-1]+".pdf", ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

    request.setNotificationConfig(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            getString(R.string.app_name),
            getString(R.string.uploading),
            getString(R.string.upload_success),
            getString(R.string.upload_error),
            false);

    // if you comment the following line, the system default user-agent will be used
    request.setCustomUserAgent("UploadServiceDemo/1.0");

    // set the intent to perform when the user taps on the upload notification.
    // currently tested only with intents that launches an activity
    // if you comment this line, no action will be performed when the user taps
    // on the notification
    // request.setNotificationClickIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

    // set the maximum number of automatic upload retries on error
    request.setMaxRetries(2);

    try {
        request.startUpload();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Malformed upload request. " + exc.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

But the problem is, it will throw null pointer exception, which I don't quite get the reason.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
        at com.fyp.mycyberlaw.Lecturer.UploadNotesActivity.onUploadButtonClick(UploadNotesActivity.java:73)
        at com.fyp.mycyberlaw.Lecturer.UploadNotesActivity.access$100(UploadNotesActivity.java:19)
        at com.fyp.mycyberlaw.Lecturer.UploadNotesActivity$2.onClick(UploadNotesActivity.java:53)
```

line 73: `if (getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath").isEmpty())`

line 19: `public class UploadNotesActivity extends Activity`

line 53: `onUploadButtonClick();`

Seems like the filePath in line 73 is empty and the way I save filePath into bundle (?) is incorrect. How to get the filePath from `onActivityResult`? Here's  the [.java](https://github.com/August08/MyCyberLaw/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fyp/mycyberlaw/Lecturer/UploadNotesActivity.java) class, just in case. Thank you in advance. Really need your help.

Comment: The `getIntent()` method returns the `Intent` that was used to start the current `Activity`. It has nothing to do with the data `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`. Instead, in that method, just save `data.getData().getPath()` to a String field, and use that in `onUploadButtonClick()`.

Comment: I changed in `onActivityResult()` to `String filePath = data.getData().getPath();
            data.putExtra("filePath", filePath);`

but I don't quite get it by `use that in onUploadButtonClick()`.. how?

Comment: No, don't try to put anything in that Intent. Just save the path, and use it in place of `getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath")` in the `onUploadButtonClick()` method. And your `String filePath` should be declared outside of any method; i.e., global to the Activity.

Comment: you mean, save the path, like `String filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath");` globally?

Comment: `String filePath;` goes outside any method. `filePath = data.getData().getPath();` goes in `onActivityResult()`. Stop using `getIntent()` for anything.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and answer! it works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Intent`object is used to pass params between activities. Ones you receives the file path you must to keep it in your activity.

Create a `filePath`variable inside your activity, set it on `onActivityResult` and read it on `onUploadButtonClick`.

Notice that must save variable value during the `onSaveInstanceState` callback and restore it in `onCreate` because every time you turn your phone the activity is destroyed and recreated. Check this for more information: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)